# Auth.js Email Provider (Magic Link) Not Redirecting to Proper URL

Tags: reactjs, typescript, email, next.js, next-auth

I am using auth.js and the magic link email provider with Resend, Typescript, Next.js 14 and SMTP.

I am able to successfully send the email and the link to sign in. However, when I click the link to sign in from the email I am redirected to this: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/email?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fconfirm-email&token=fe6e7a9e95588dae7a1b91ee333e602b026d0375eba9ff3ba5d38dd02cae2b28&email=dabrettwestwood%40gmail.com

Even though I should be redirected to http://localhost:3000/confirm-email.

Here is my server action code where it happens.

```
"use server";

import { LoginSchema } from "@/schemas";
import { z } from "zod";
import { signIn } from "@/auth";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/database";

export const login = async (values: z.infer<typeof LoginSchema>) => {

  const confirmationLink = 'http://localhost:3000/confirm-email'

  //   Check to see if data is valid
  const isValid = LoginSchema.safeParse(values);
  console.log(isValid);


  if (!isValid.success) {
    throw new Error("Email is not valid");
  }

  const { email } = isValid.data;


  signIn("email", { email, redirectTo: confirmationLink });



  return { success: `Email sent to ${email}` };
};
```

As you can the redirectTo is the confirmationLink variable which is is http://localhost:3000/confirm-email.

You can see this URL in that messy URL above after the callbackURL query.

I need help being able to navigate to the proper page.

Here is my auth.config.ts file

```
import { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email';

export default {
    providers: [
        EmailProvider({
            id: 'email',
            name: 'email',
            server: {
                host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
                port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
                    pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD
                }
            },
            from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM
        })
    ]
} satisfies NextAuthConfig
```

Here is my auth.ts file

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import {PrismaAdapter} from '@auth/prisma-adapter';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import authConfig from './auth.config';

const db = new PrismaClient();

export const {
     handlers: { GET, POST },
     auth,
     signIn
} = NextAuth({
     pages: {
      signIn: '/sign-in',
     },
     callbacks: {
          async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
               console.log("Redirect URL", url);
               console.log("Redirect Base URL", baseUrl);
               return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
          },
          async session({ token, session }) {
               console.log("Session Token", token);
        
     
               return session;
             }, 
             async jwt({ token }) {
      console.log("JWT Token", token);
               return token;
             },
     },
     adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
     session: {
       strategy: "jwt",
     },
     ...authConfig
})
```

Let me know if you need to see anymore of my code.